# Why doesn't `geth` have `--rpcapi` option?

Tags: go-ethereum, smart-contract-wallets

I am new to `Ethereum` and trying to setup a private network by using `geth` command. I have installed `geth`:

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.12-stable
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.17.2
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

I have read some doc about how to launch a node in private network and many mentioned to use a command like `geth --datadir=./chaindata/ --ipcpath $HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal,miner`.

However, I got this error `flag provided but not defined: -rpcapi` on above command. And I checked the geth doc https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options but it doesn't have any option for `rpcapi`. Is this flag deprecated? what is the alternative one I should use?

In the end, I end up using `geth --datadir data/node1 --http --dev --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net --mine` command to launch the node. Is there anything different by using `http` than `rpc`?

One issue I have is after I attach to the console, `geth attach http://localhost:8545`, I can't find `miner` instance: `ReferenceError: miner is not defined`. How can I get the miner in order to mine more ether for my accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't `geth` have `--rpcapi` option?

Because the --rpc* flags were changed in favor of --http* (--rpc became --http and --rpcapi became --http.api), support for the legacy --rpc* flags was dropped on [geth 1.10.9](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.9).

> How can I get the miner in order to mine more ether for my accounts?

You need to enable the [miner namespace](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-miner) too as you did in your first command:

```
geth --datadir data/node1 --http --dev --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net,miner --mine
```

Comment: If you look at my command in the post, I already have `--mine` but still get the error `miner is not defined`

Comment: Look again in the flags following `--http.api` you did include `miner` in your first command using `--rpcapi` but not in the one using `--http.api` (second command). You are not activating the miner namespace on the http.api.

Comment: yes, you are 100% correct